# Strategy for prioritizing data updates and maintenance in a data-heavy app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-design

I've got a Rails app with tens of thousands of records that I poll an API to get updates on. I'm wondering what's the best practices in terms of creating a system (more involved than just a cron job) that tracks how often a record should be updated...some records are more important/timely than others...so for regular maintenance, I want more important records to be polled and updated twice a day , compared to once a day for non-important records.

So assuming these records have some method that returns their "importance"...should I create a type of maintenance_record model that `belongs_to` each record and keeps track of that record's staleness (a combination of that record's updated_at and its importance)? This record would also log whether the latest attempt was successful or not, and perhaps have a foreign key into a table of log records.

The purpose is to have `maintenance_record` be something that is very quick to index and sort so that a cron-like job can scan the list for jobs to do, rather than hitting the `records` database (which may contain records with lots of blobs, etc. and may grow by orders of magnitude). And of course, I have more than one kind of record-like Model...so having a polymorphic `maintenance_record` seems sensible.

Anyway, is this a good idea? It seems like a scenario that would come up often so I was wondering if there were any libraries that may deal specifically with it, though I imagine creating a simple one isn't too hard.

Comment: This is a pretty nebulous description. It would help a lot for you to show summarized/minimal examples of your table schemas instead of asking us to imagine what they might be.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be vague. It's just that the actual schema of the data tables seems orthogonal to the mechanism that would update them, right? It's basically a question of: should the columns related to updated_time and staleness need to be moved to another table, if the main records table becomes large enough...or is that optimization not worth the effort?

Comment: It's not worth the effort in my mind. If you're going to need that information for more than 40% of the queries against that database, then add them as fields to the record. I say 40%, because you're going to have overhead joining tables or doing sub-selects, to retrieve that data if it's separated from the main record and that overhead needs to be calculated into the cost of record access.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when I've needed to periodically update records, I add a `modified_at` timestamp field that gets updated each time the record changes.

Then, on a cron schedule, I look through the table for records that are beyond a certain time, process and update the row and its `modified_at` field.

If there are priorities/importance, add a field and set a level for each record. If 1 is the top and 2 is the next lower, then every cycle process fields with `priority == 1`. Every other cycle process records with `priority <= 2`.

How you should process both those fields is left as an exercise for you.